# dart pub upgrade not taking my dependencies constraints into consideration

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    dependencies: 
      test: ^1.19.3
```

> I had my test dependency purposely downgraded.In my package, test's constraints were ^1.19.3. After I ran dart pub upgrade, it upgraded my test to 1.20.0 and it was visible in pubspec.lock even if my app depended on ^1.19.3 it kept it as it is and ignored it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as intended: the `^` symbol indicates packages up to the next major version (in your example up to version 2.0.0) will upgrade with `pub upgrade`.  If you want to lock to an exact version (not recommended) then you just remove the caret symbol (`^`).

See [here](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#version-constraints) for more details.

Comment: I get it but mine is ^1.19.3 so it should be less than 1.20.0 and pub upgrade shouldn't change it right

Comment: As it should always be less that breaking version

Comment: No, the caret will upgrade up to (but not including) the next major version, which is the first number before the dot, so in your example it will upgrade up to (but not including) 2.0.0. It is therefore correct in upgrading from 1.19.3 to 1.20.0 as that is a *minor* version increase and should be non-breaking. Again, if you want to lock to a specific version just remove the caret.